# How to search for specific files in file explorer

Tags: windows

I am looking for files that begin with a b (or B) and contain only numbers afterwards. If I search for b* I get all files starting with b but this is more than I want. I think the search I am looking for is something like b*+[0-9] but I am not sure exactly what it is.

Comment: Try `*1234*`. Explorer searches only support `*` and `?`. See [Learning Windows Search: Use Boolean, Dates, and Wildcards to Give Your Searches a Boost](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/learning-windows-search/lesson4/)

Comment: The rest of the articles in that series is also worth reading ...

Comment: My question was phrased poorly, I edited it to clarify what I am trying to do

Comment: I read through the article but wasn't able to find the solution

Comment: There isn't one. See my first comment. Explorer searches only support `*` and `?`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a third-party tool, such as [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/), which performs non-indexed searches, or [Doc Fetcher](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html), which builds indexes on files (including some file types that MS Windows Search does not handle) and performs *fast*, indexed, searches. Both applications allow the use of regexp on at least filenames, and perhaps on contents..

Comment: +1 for Agent Ransack.